# Tornado.access:500 POST error with IPython 2.0.0 on Python 3.3.5

Tags: python, ipython, tornado

I keep getting an error when trying to run code from one of my IPython notebooks (the notebooks themselves open up fine, I'm just unable to run any code and view the output).

The complete error is:

```
ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /api/sessions (127.0.0.1) 13.01ms referrer=http://127.0.0.1:8888/notebooks/untitled0.ipynb.
```

I'm running Python 3.3.5, IPython 2.0.0 via an install from easy_install on a windows 8 machine.

I tried reinstalling (uninstall via pip, reinstall via easy_install) the tornado package, IPython, it was of no use.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When I used `anaconda`, I met a similar problem .

Try

```
pip install simplejson
```

This works for me

This page talks about a similar problem and solution.

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1966/

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was using Holoviews package in the IPynb and I was caught by similar error. Then I found that if try to plot a dataframe in the server rather than a "Series", this error shows up. I dont know thw complete reason for this, but to all those who are getting the similar error,
kindly change your data to Series and then plot it in server
Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Any Ideas on why is this happening?